# If the boat were to capsize, it’s designed to re-right itself

Tags: conditional-constructions

The following conditional sentence is hard to reconcile with traditional grammar. I'm wondering what makes it okay as a conditional sentence and how to make sense of it in a way that conforms to grammar. Preferably, I'd prefer to see similar examples.

> Harley will make his idea a reality when he launches himself into the Atlantic in a 24-foot boat. It’s designed to handle less-than-ideal conditions. “If the boat **were to** capsize, **it’s** designed to re-right itself,” Harley said.

https://edition.cnn.com/2022/04/28/us/peter-harley-solo-row-us-to-france-trnd/index.html

Comment: Is Harley really a sailor? I'm used to hearing people who use such boats (they are not new) saying e.g. 'it's designed to **right itself**'. Is that your problem? What is the 'traditional grammar' that you think is violated?

Comment: You might want to study the types of conditionals in traditional grammar and see if the OP sentence fits any of them.

Comment: _**If** the boat **were to capsize** (subjunctive) then it **would** right itself, as it is designed to do_ - Is that what you're thinking of? - Harley is clearly more of a sailor than he is a grammarian.

Comment: Yes, that's standard conditional, but curiously, you saw nothing wrong about the OP sentence. Why?

Comment: Probably because native speakers are not taught about 'conditionals', which are mainly a teaching tool used to teach English as a foreign language. Native speakers can deviate from these 'rules' and often nobody really notices.

Comment: I'm looking for rules or generalizations that determine when such deviations are acceptable. I don't think just any deviations from standard conditionals are natural.

Comment: You want a rule about when it's OK to break a rule?

Comment: Yes. Certain deviations are okay, and others are not. Why?

Comment: This is an area most ESL teachers shun.

Comment: Well, I'm going to shun it as well, except perhaps to mention that many formal usages taught as 'rules' to ESL students are partly or completely ignored by native speakers, especially in casual or informal speech. The subjunctive is very widely ignored. You may consider the 'rules' to be examples of the 'pedagogic lie' (or 'lie-to-children'), a useful oversimplification that starts one on the path to better knowledge. For example, in arithmetic we happily teach children that 'you cannot take 3 from 2' because we are confident that someone will later introduce them to negative numbers

Comment: I don't see anything syntactically questionable here The writer made the ***stylistic choice*** to use subjunctive rather than plain *If the boat **capsizes**, it's designed to re-right itself* because that more strongly implies that capsizing is relatively unlikely. Much the same could be said about tautologous ***re-right*** rather than plain ***right***, where that "unnecessary" prefix ***re-*** more strongly emphasises "returning to ***previous*** state" as well as being "the ***right*** way up".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I believe the words were spoken in an interview.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The writer / the speaker. Doesn't really make any difference. We're certainly not talking about any kind of *spoken **colloquial*** context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is something syntactically odd about it. Why is the matching of the subjunctive clause with the indicative main clause okay? That does not seem possible in most cases. I'm wondering when such deviations are acceptable.

Comment: @Apollyon: As Colin says, the "verb mood" of two clauses don't need to match if the second clause isn't a "consequence" of the first. Consider, *If you **were** to develop some dread disease, [**at least**] you **live** in a country with a sophisticated health care system.* Maybe not the best example, but things like that are perfectly natural in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harley has put things in an order which unfortunately means that, if you group the words together in the most natural way, you get an absurd result. Here's one way to say what Harley really meant:

"The boat's designed to re-right itself if it were to capsize."

That is, the conditional "if it were to capsize" is meant as part of the phrase saying what the boat's designed to do.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing odd about the sentence, except that (as is reasonably common in everyday English), the second clause is not the consequent of the conditional at all, but a (logically) independent sentence whose connection with the conditional can be filled in by real-world experience.

A logically complete version would be *If the boat were to capsize, it would re-right itself, because it’s designed to do so*.

It's similar to sentences like *If you want anything, I'll be just down the corridor*.

Comment: Is " If you want anything, I'll be just down the corridor" equivalent to " In case you want anything, I'm telling you I'll be just down the corridor"?

Comment: Yes, @Apollyon, it is. It would be odd to include "I'm telling you" though.

Comment: There's an implicit *If such-and-such **were** to happen, **it wouldn't matter, because** the system is designed to cope with that possibility* (where using the subjunctive rather than *If that **did** happen* carries to implication ***in the remote eventuality*** rather than plain ***if/when***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was looking for examples involving counterfactual if-clauses with then-clauses omitted.

Comment: @Apollyon: I'm not sure what you mean by "with then-clauses omitted". The actual word "then" isn't present in, for example, [*if something untoward were to happen, we have a clear path to dealing with it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22if+something+untoward+were+to+happen+we+have%22), but surely it's ***always*** implied. That's regardless of whether the second assertion refers to the *consequence* of the first one becoming true, or simply makes some secondary associated assertion which only becomes contextually relevant ***if*** the first situation arises.

Comment: *If a live unicorn **were** to be found, we have the biotech to clone enough to meet global demand*. That looks pretty "counterfactual" to me! :)

Comment: Thank you. Is this okay for you? "If he **freaked** out, his wife **is** there to calm him down."